# List posts by category in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm new to CakePHP. Please help me to write a function to retrieve posts under a particular category for my blog app built using CakePHP.

My table structure:

posts: id, post, body, created, category_id
category: id, group

Also I had defined:
Inside post model - `var $belongsTo = 'Category';`
Inside category model - `var $hasMany = 'Post';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) is the generic *query* method for Models in CakePHP.

An example would be:

```
$results = $this->Post->find('recursive' => -1, 'conditions' => array('Post.category_id' => 1));
debug($results);
```

There are many ways to achieve what you want. I encourage you to [read the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) or working through the [CakePHP Blog Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Post.category_id' => $category_id)));
```

where $category_id is the id of category that you want to retrieve results from database

hope this helps